# Interpreting minimum_should_match for elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm very new to elasticsearch query, I'm hoping to get some clarification with the following query of an existing source code that I'm looking at.

```
body["query"]["bool"]["should"] = [
    {"match": {"categories": {"query": raw_query, "operator": "and"}}},
    ....,
    ....,
    {"match": {"all": {"query": raw_query, "minimum_should_match": "50%" if keywords else "2<80%"}}}
]
body["query"]["bool"]["minimum_should_match"] = 1
```

My understanding of `minimum_should_match` is that it specifies the number of minimum matching words to the query. For example, for the following, any 2 of the 3 words `young`, `transformation` and `Egyptian` satisfies as a match for the `description` field.

```
"query":{
    "match":{
        "description":{
          "query" : "young transformation Egyptian",
          "minimum_should_match" : 2
        } 
    }
  }
```

From the source code I understand `"minimum_should_match": "50%"` that means as long as half of the words in `raw_query` matches what is in the field `all` if there are `keywords`. What confuses me a bit is `2<80%`. I've read the docs but I'm still confused.

From the docs, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html, it gave an example of `3<90%` and says:

```
if there are 1 to 3 clauses they are all required, but for 4 or more clauses only 90% are required.
```

What exactly is the `clause`? I would think the clause is every `match` statement in this case but from the source code, this is placed within a single `match` clause. In that case, how can it ever have more than one clause? My understanding is obviously incorrect.

The last part I need confirmation on is:

```
body["query"]["bool"]["minimum_should_match"] = 1
```

Since it is placed outside of `should`, does that mean only a single `match` from `body["query"]["bool"]["should"]` is required?

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding of minimum_should_match is that it specifies the number of minimum matching words to the query.

Not always. Here `minimum_should_match` applies not to specific full-text queries but to the `bool` query and controls how many of `should` clauses should trigger.

If `minimum_should_match` is applied to a specific `match` query then yes, it will control how many tokens (words) should match.